# C++ dll called from managed C++/cli doesn't print cout statements

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, c++-cli

I am new to C++. My question may be stupid but, any help would be appreciated.

I have a dll (we don't have source code for this dll) written in C++ unmanaged code which I tried calling from C# P/Invoke but, couldn't get the cout statement to print on the Console window of a console application.

Out of desperation I created a C++ managed dll wrapper to call the earlier mentioned dll and then referenced that managed dll in C# console app which doesn't help as well.

I was only able to print the cout statements from C++ win32 app.
Unmanaged dll function interface is as follow:

```
HRESULT WINAPI Foo(int len, LPCWSTR[] arg);
```

The managed dll c++/cli is consuming the above function as follow:

```
int Footool::FooMain(String ^ wargv, String ^ outFileName) {
wstring fileName = L"";
MarshalString(outFileName, fileName);

streambuf *psbuf, *backup;
ofstream filestr;
filestr.open(fileName);
backup = cout.rdbuf();
psbuf = filestr.rdbuf();
cout.rdbuf(psbuf);

cout << "Entering FooMain." << endl;
HINSTANCE fooDll = LoadLibrary(L"foo.dll");
if (fooDll == NULL) {
    throw "foo.dll is not loaded.";
}

wstring args = L"";
MarshalString(wargv, args);
cout << args.c_str() << endl;

vector<wstring> arguments = split(args, ' ');
cout << "Size of the arguments: ";

for (wstring& s : arguments) {
    cout << s.c_str() << endl;
}

LPCWSTR *lpcwstrArray = new LPCWSTR[arguments.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < arguments.size(); i++) {
    lpcwstrArray[i] = arguments.at(i).c_str();
}

fooFunc sign = (fooFunc)GetProcAddress(fooDll, "Foo");
if (sign == NULL) {
    throw "Could not load Foo method.";
}

cout << "Calling foo.dll." << endl;
HRESULT result = sign(arguments.size(), lpcwstrArray);
FreeLibrary(fooDll);
cout << "Exiting FooMain." << endl;
cout.rdbuf(backup);
filestr.close();
return (int)result;
```

}

C# P/Invoke attempt:

```
        [DllImport("foo.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "Foo", ExactSpelling = false,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int Foo
    (
        int argc,
        string[] argv
    );
```

Caller:

```
public static main()
{
string[] parameters = {"some", "Valid", "parameters"};  
int returnResult = Foo(parameters.Length, parameters);
// try reading from console.
    StreamWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
    standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
    Console.SetOut(standardOutput);
    Console.SetError(standardOutput);                

}
```

Is there a way to print the cout statements to console using C#? Having said that I tried number of solutions on stack overflow mentioning NamedPipe, AnonymousPipe etc which didn't work as well.

Thanks

Comment: What does the interface to your dll look like, I guess there's a header file that goes with it, show us an example of a function from there.

Comment: I don't have the header file, I just do LoadLibray("foo.dll") from managed c++/cli dll. I have edited the question with more details.

Comment: Well, you're overcomplicating thing here. What's `MarshalString`? Why don't you use the marshaling function provided [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx)? Also, you're going through the trouble of loading your lib dynamically for no good reason. But now I get why you could have had issues with P/Invoke, it's not quite straightforward when arrays are involved. If your final goal is to call that from C# then post your attempt and let's work from there, and skip the C++/CLI part altogether.

Comment: I didn't know how to pass char* from C# so, I pass the string and marshal them in the C++. I wrote this C++/Cli wrapper by assuming that it will print to console. It prints cout statements in the function but doesn't print the cout in method HRESULT WINAPI Foo(int len, LPCWSTR[] arg); Hence, I didn't get any advantage using crl wrapper it's just behaving the same way it behaved while P/Invoking

Comment: MarshalString is a function to convert System.String to std::wstring. I got that method from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b4az623.aspx

Comment: Try the following P/Invoke signature from C#, see if you can get it to work: `extern int Foo(int len, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string[] arg)`

Comment: Also, `WINAPI` means `CallingConvention.Stdcall`, not cdecl. Just use the default: `[DllImport("foo.dll")]` should be enough.

Comment: I will try your suggestion by changing CallingConvention to Stdcall but, it won't print I believe. I have edited question with the P/Invoke attempt. It's working fine but, I am not able to capture some vital cout information from the dll. If dll has some error it's not throwing any it just prints and we are loosing the debugging capability with this solution.

Comment: You can't capture unmanaged standard output with `Console.SetOut`, this only redirects *managed* calls. You'll have to use [`SetStdHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686244.aspx) for this. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19323929/3764814) for an example.

Comment: I tried `SetStdHandle` as per your comment but, It's doesn't work for some reason.